# How to convert an EBCDIC zoned decimal to a decimal in MS SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, bcd

Hi everyone this is major chunk for me I have been trying lot but not getting success 
there is data in db as [AH_TRAN_CV] of length 9 as Integer. and I want that in varchar with 9 char and 2 decimals. 

I guess this whole code may be wrong as I don't have knowledge just used internet to get till here.. The sample is like

```
123D is +1234
678{ is +6780
468K is -4682
Digit Positive Negative 
0         {        }
1         A        J
2         B        K
3         C        L
4         D        M
5         E        N
6         F        O
7         G        P
8         H        Q
9         I        R
```

So kindly help. Below is just part of code
Code :

```
Case When (substring(convert(varchar,[AH_TRAN_CV] * 0.0000001), 9, 1)  = '4' 
      and ([AH_TRAN_CV] >= 0.00)) 
        Then concat (substring(convert(varchar,[AH_TRAN_CV]*0.0000001), 3, 8), 'D')
end [AH_TRAN_CV]
```

Comment: **I want 123D convert to +1234**

Comment: Edit your question, don't add what you actually want as a comment.

Comment: You aren't *converting* anything. You are trying to parse an EBCDIC zoned string as a number. You can't do that with a simple character replacement. There is no built-in functionality for such a thing except maybe in IBM mainframes?

Comment: Okay there may be no inbuilt functionality but there should be a way to do it can you let me know.. It would be very helpful for me.

Comment: That kind of encoding isn't used since the 80s outside mainframes. You should convert it to actual strings or numbers when loading the data to SQL Server. The only reason I know what this is is because airlines use this format to export reports to customers from their mainframes. Airlines were the first companies to actually use mainframes so this became a kind of fossilized standard

Answer (score 2):

This encoding isn't a numeric format that can be parsed to a number. It's an [EBCDIC zoned decimal encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal#EBCDIC_zoned_decimal_conversion_table) found only in mainframes.

You can create a function that splits the string and generates the appropriate sign and last digit from the input string, eg :

```
create function ZonedToNumber(@somenum varchar(20))
returns varchar(20)
as
begin

declare @c char = right(@somenum,1);

declare @digit char = case when @c between 'A' and 'I' then (ascii(@c) -64)
                        when @c between 'J' and 'R' then (ascii(@c) -73)
                        when @c in ('{','}') then 0
                        else null end

declare @sign char = case when @c between 'A' and 'I' or @c = '{' then '+'
                    when @c between 'J' and 'R' or @c = '}' then '-'
                    else null end

RETURN CONCAT(@sign,left(@somenum,len(@somenum)-1)  ,@digit)
end
```

Instead of performing any clever arithmetic, the function uses `CASE` and subtracts a base ASCII value for each case to generate the last digit and sign.

You can apply that function to a zoned decimal string to convert it to an actual number, eg: `SELECT dbo.ZonedToNumber('1234')` will return `=1234`. You can also use it in a query :

```
declare @t table (num varchar(20))
insert into @t 
values
('123D'),
('123K'),
('123{'),
('123}')

select cast(dbo.ZonedToNumber(num) as int)
from @t x
```

This will return :

```
1234
-1232
1230
-1230
```

You should use this function only to convert zoned decimals to actual numbers when loading the data. Almost nobody (outside mainframes) uses this format anymore.